# Evitar registros duplicados y contabilizarlos

Tags: mysql

Tengo una consulta en la que obtengo un listado de empresas

```
SELECT S.FileB64 AS ImgB64, E.* FROM dbempresas E
    LEFT JOIN systorage S ON S.id = E.Logo_100 
    ORDER BY E.Nombre;

RESULTADO:
id |     RFC      |           Nombre
---+--------------+----------------------------------
14 | AAA010101AAA | ACCEM SERVICIOS EMPRESARIALES SC
15 | BBB010101BBB | CORPORACION ACME
16 | CCC010101CCC | INDUSTRIAS KORD
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero **quiero añadirle cuantas sucursales hay por empresa** arrojándome un resultado como esto:

```
id |     RFC      |           Nombre                    |  Sucursales
---+--------------+-------------------------------------+--------------
14 | AAA010101AAA | ACCEM SERVICIOS EMPRESARIALES SC    |    2
15 | BBB010101BBB | CORPORACION ACME                    |    1
16 | CCC010101CCC | INDUSTRIAS KORD                     |    1
```

Para intentar lograr lo anterior he hecho esto:

```
SELECT S.FileB64 AS ImgB64, ES.id, E.* FROM dbempresas E
    LEFT JOIN systorage S ON S.id = E.Logo_100 
    LEFT JOIN dbempresas_sucursales ES ON ES.IdEmpresa = E.id
    ORDER BY E.Nombre;

RESULTADO:
id |     RFC      |           Nombre                    |  ES.id
---+--------------+-------------------------------------+--------------
14 | AAA010101AAA | ACCEM SERVICIOS EMPRESARIALES SC    |    13
14 | AAA010101AAA | ACCEM SERVICIOS EMPRESARIALES SC    |    16
15 | BBB010101BBB | CORPORACION ACME                    |    17
16 | CCC010101CCC | INDUSTRIAS KORD                     |    18
```

Se que con `COUNT()` puedo contar los registros pero no tengo idea de como lograrlo en una misma query.
**¿Como puedo evitar que se repita el `id` de la empresa y me de el resultado que deseo?**

Estas son las tablas en las que hago las consultas:

```
+------------------------------+   +-------------------------------+
|          dbEmpresas          |   |     dbEmpresas_Sucursales     |
+-------------+----------------+   +-------------+-----------------+
|  id         |  bigint(20)    |   |  id         |  bigint(20)     |
|  RFC        |  varchar(15)   |   |  IdEmpresa  |  bigint(20)     |
|  Nombre     |  varchar(100)  |   |  Nombre     |  varchar(100)   |
|  Logo_100   |  bigint(20)    |   +-------------+-----------------+
+-------------+----------------+

+-----------------------------+
|          syStorage          | 
+-----------+-----------------+
|  id       |  bigint(20)     |
|  FileB64  |  text           |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo único que te falta en realidad es que le hagas un `GROUP BY` por todas las columnas que no vengan de la tabla `dbEmpresas_Sucursales`. Con eso, ahora sí puedes usar la función `COUNT` correctamente y sin resultados erróneos.

```
SELECT S.FileB64 AS ImgB64, E.*, COUNT(ES.id) AS Sucursales
FROM dbempresas E
LEFT JOIN systorage S ON S.id = E.Logo_100 
LEFT JOIN dbempresas_sucursales ES ON ES.IdEmpresa = E.id
GROUP BY E.id, E.RFC, E.Nombre, E.Logo_100, S.FileB64
ORDER BY E.Nombre;
```

Comment: yo muy cercas y a la vez tan lejos :D, no me paso por la mente el `Group By`